# Reset bootstrap button state

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form with a few toggle buttons:

```
  <div id="options-group" class="row">
    <button id="burning-option-button" class="btn option-toggle-button" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off"></button>
    <button id="flacky-cocktail-button" class="btn option-toggle-button" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off"></button>
    <button id="ice-cocktail-button" class="btn option-toggle-button" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off"></button>
    <button id="official-cocktail-button" class="btn option-toggle-button" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off"></button>
    <button id="checked-cocktail-button" class="btn option-toggle-button" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off"></button>
  </div>
```

Now I want to add button with possibility to reset states of that buttons.
What the best way to "unselect" toggled buttons using jquery/js?

I'm using Bootstrap3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$('button.active').removeClass('active');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fpdwef37/

Comment: Thanks! Seems it works. But should I also set "aria-pressed" attribute to false? Because now it still "true" despite inactive state.

Comment: yes if the attribute changes, in my jsfiddle it doesn't that is why i didn't put it in my code